# Undefined Index error when uploading files

Tags: php, html, file

So, I have a form with two input elements: one to upload a file, and the other, a hidden input. Here it is:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST">
    upload: <input enctype="multipart/form-data" name="pp" accept="image/png" type="file">
    <input type="submit" value="go" />
    <input type="hidden" name="eup" />
</form>
```

on my "upload.php" page (which is a different page), I get the undefined index error. Here's the code for that:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["eup"])){
    $fERR=false;

    if(isset($_FILES["pp"])){ // undefined index error comes if this IF is removed...
        $aExts = array("png");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["pp"]["name"]);
        $tEXT = end($temp);

        if ((($_FILES["pp"]["type"]=="image/x-png")
        || ($_FILES["pp"]["type"]=="image/png"))
        && ($_FILES["pp"]["size"]<300000)
        && in_array($tEXT, $aExts)){
            if ($_FILES["pp"]["error"]>0){
                $ppERR=true;
                }
            else{
                // handle file upload here
                }
            }
        else{
            $fERR=true;
            }
        }
    else{
        $fERR=true;
        }

    if($fERR==true){
        echo "ERROR";
        }else{
        echo "GOOD TO GO";
        }
    }
    echo "<br />".ini_get("file_uploads");
?>
```

I've looked at a bunch of other posts and websites discussing this topic, but none of the solutions worked for me.

by the way, the output of that php is:

```
ERROR
1
```

Comment: enctype is set on the form, not the input: `<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: You will need to post the full error if you need more help

Comment: I've never seen `$_FILES["pp"]["error"]`, what sets the `error` and what is it for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    upload: <input name="pp" accept="image/png" type="file">
    <input type="submit" value="go" />
    <input type="hidden" name="eup" />
</form>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks for your time!